# Using Guavas Range in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, guava

I would like to use Guavas [Range](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Range.html) from Scala. However it expects the elements to implement the `Comparable` interface. So I cannot simply use

```
val range = Range.open(4, 5)
```

since `Int` does not implement `Comparable` or `Ordered`. However there is an `Ordering[Int]` type class. The only idea I have so far is to use view bounds

```
def open[T](from:T, to:T)(implicit ord: T => Ordered[T]) = Range.open(ord(from), ord(to))
```

but I get a CCE:

```
 val range = open(4,5)                           //> java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.runtime.RichInt cannot be cast to java.l
                                                  //| ang.Integer
                                                  //|   at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(BoxesRunTime.java:106)
                                                  //|   at scala.math.Ordering$Int$.compare(Ordering.scala:256)
                                                  //|   at scala.runtime.OrderedProxy$class.compare(ScalaNumberProxy.scala:71)
                                                  //|   at scala.runtime.RichInt.compare(RichInt.scala:15)
                                                  //|   at scala.math.Ordered$class.compareTo(Ordered.scala:91)
                                                  //|   at scala.runtime.RichInt.compareTo(RichInt.scala:15)
                                                  //|   at com.google.common.collect.Range.compareOrThrow(Range.java:711)
                                                  //|   at com.google.common.collect.Cut.compareTo(Cut.java:75)
                                                  //|   at com.google.common.collect.Range.<init>(Range.java:364)
                                                  //|   at com.google.common.collect.Range.create(Range.java:156)
                                                  //|   at com.google.common.collect.Range.open(Range.java:168)
```

**Why does this result in a ClassCastException?**

Is there a better way to do this? Note: using `Int` is just a minimal example. I have more complex types that don't implement `Ordered` but with an `Ordering` in scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an CCE because `RichInt` does not implement `Ordered[RichInt]` but `Ordered[Int]`.

I suggest you wrap it by yourself similar to

```
case class AsOrdered[T](val value: T)(implicit ord: Ordering[T]) extends Ordered[AsOrdered[T]] {
  override def compare(that: AsOrdered[T]) = ord.compare(value, that.value)
}

def open[T: Ordering](from: T, to: T) = {
  val ord = implicitly[Ordering[T]]
  Range.open(AsOrdered(from), AsOrdered(to))
}
```

You need to provide additional logic to extract the values since you will not get a `Range[Int]` but a `Range[AsOrdered[Int]]`

**Edit:**

We just released a version of [Mango](https://github.com/feijoas/mango) that contains a [Range](http://feijoas.github.io/mango/scaladoc/index.html#org.feijoas.mango.common.collect.Range)/[RangeSet](http://feijoas.github.io/mango/scaladoc/index.html#org.feijoas.mango.common.collect.RangeSet) wrapping the Guava implementations taking an `Ordering`.

Answer (score 4):

Just explicitly specify that you want to box to a `java.lang.Integer`:

```
import java.lang.{Integer => jI}
Range.open[jI](3,5)
```

If you don't like doing this on every call, wrap the calls as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks. I would prefer to wrap it. Do you have any explanation why I get the ClassCastException? I don't see a mistake in the way I defined `def open` nor the way I call it.

Comment: @ManuelSchmidt - I guess it's a bug in `RichInt` not unboxing properly?  Not sure.  In any case, you don't need `RichInt`, so you can force it to go to `java.lang.Integer` as I showed above.